# $.colorbox.close(); colorbox close issue

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have tried to close the colorbox window while clicking the button. the window should be a ajax paged window.

I have tried with example page , the inline button can able to close, the same code i have written in the ajax paged but it throws the error in console firebug ie

```
**"TypeError: $.colorbox is undefined


(9 out of range 6)"**
```

I really don't know the meaning of the error.

My HTML Code is .index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<title>Colorbox Examples</title>
<style>
body {
    font:12px/1.2 Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding:0 10px;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#416CE5;
    border-bottom:1px solid #416CE5;
}
h2 {
    font-size:13px;
    margin:15px 0 0 0;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $(".ajax").colorbox();
                $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});

                $('#test_close').click('cbox_closed',function(e){
                     $('#test_close').colorbox.close();
                }); 

            });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<p><a class='ajax' href="http://localhost/karthiga/demo/colorbox-master/content/ajax.html" title="Homer Defined">Outside HTML (Ajax)</a></p>
<p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a></p>
<!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls -->
<div style='display:none'>
  <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
    <p> Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem </p>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="test_close">Close</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the ajax page is : ajax.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#test_close1').click('cbox_closed',function(e){
                alert('');
                     $.colorbox.close();
                }); 
            });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<p> Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum </p>
<br/>
<br/>
<p><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="test_close1">Close</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: This is typically thrown when the colorbox file is not loaded.  Are you sure that the file is at `../jquery.colorbox.js`. You can use Firebug's Network tab to see if it's being loaded or getting a 404.

Comment: I have given the absolute path too, but getting the same error and not close the colorbox :(

Comment: So the colorbox is showing, just not closing?  That would mean your issue is somewhere in the ajax.html. You might still check to see that the file is being loaded using Firebug's Network tab. I just tested with http://jsfiddle.net/5PSLe/ and it works for me.

Comment: The script is loading in firebug network's tab..but still not working for me..i duknow how to fix that :( and am in corner now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I loaded a full example on my workstation and found two issues.

1. When Colorbox loads a page using AJAX, it actually inlines the
   resulting HTML. Since your ajax.html file is loading jQuery and the
   Colorbox widget again, it is causing issues.  So, remove the two
   `<script>` tags in your ajax.html file.
2. In index.html you
   have a call to `$('#test_close').colorbox.close();`. Replace this
   with `$.colorbox.close();`.

These should fix your issues.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Put this inside your ajax.html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test_close1').click(function(){
            parent.$.colorbox.close();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#test_close').click('cbox_closed',function(e){
    $.fn.colorbox.close();
});
```

Comment: Getting error : TypeError: $.fn.colorbox is undefined
 

(9 out of range 6)